# Get Record based on form textbox value

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access-2007

I am trying to get a record based on the value contain within the textbox on a form. i.e i type in the information into the textbox and other values associated with that value are returned to other textbox on the form.

I thought this would be easy but can't seem to get it to work.

Currently I was trying

```
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
Dim SQL As String
Dim SQL2 As String

SQL = "SELECT tblmytbl.[IDCODE]" 
"FROM tblmytbl " & _
"WHERE (((tblmytbl.[IDCODE]) = forms!myform!mybox.value " 

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rst = db.OpenRecordset(SQL)
If Not ((rst.BOF = True) And (rst.EOF = True)) Then
Forms!myform!Text102 = rst.Fields("[Name]")
Forms!myform!Text103 = rst.Fields("[Surname]")enter code here
```

Note: The search information is alphanumeric and i have tried without the .value

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL you send to the server can't access the form. However, you can concatenate the value into the string that you send like:

```
" WHERE (((mytable.myfield) = '" & FixQuotes(Forms!myform!mybox.value) & "') " & _
```

Note, you may need to defend yourself against SQL injection, a simple (but not complete) defense would be something like:

```
Public Function FixQuotes(input as string) As String
    FixQuotes = Replace(input,"'","''")
End Function
```

EDIT:

Based on your updated code, there's quite a number of changes you need to make. Beyond my statement above, the `.OpenRecordset` only applies to full tables, you can't use it with a `SELECT` statement. Instead, you have to instantiate a QueryDef. On top of that, you try to reference fields you didn't include in the query. Also, you can simplify the expression `Forms!myform!` to `Me` (which could help if you want to reuse the code somewhere else) So your code should look something like this:

```
Dim db as Database 'always dim everything, you should use Option Explicit'
Dim rst as Recordset 'DAO is the default anyway'
Dim qdf as QueryDef 'this object is required for queries'

Set db = CurrentDb

'prepare single-use query, to return the values you're going to use
'as mentioned before, the query doesn't have access to the form
'we can use Me since it references the form'
' use TOP 1 since you only expect 1 record'

Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef("","SELECT TOP 1 Name,Surname FROM tblmytbl " & _
     "WHERE IDCODE = '" & FixQuotes(Me.mybox.value) & "';")

Set rst = qdf.OpenRecordset(DbOpenForwardOnly) 
'forwardonly since you only care about the first record'

If Not rst.EOF Then 'ForwardOnly has to start at the first record'
    Me.Text102.Value = rst!Name
    Me.Text103.Value = rst!Surname
    'I highly suggest giving these boxes better names'
Else
    'no record found'
End if

rst.Close
qdf.Close
db.Close 'close these objects, it can sometimes cause memory leaks otherwise'
```

Comment: A bit over my head really. I'm not really an expert. Many thanks for your input though. Perhaps i can use this to search for some examples.

Comment: Where are you putting that string exactly?

Comment: The code runs from an onclick event on a form command button. The search criteria is help in Forms!myform!mybox. If i understood your question correctly.

Comment: Right, but are you altering the `RecordSource` of the form or the `Filter`?

Comment: I want to alter the data in the table from the from. However, to get the records i'm creating a DAO record set. Is that what you mean?

Comment: OK you're doing something else entirely. That's fine, it's hard to tell what you're trying to do from the code you posted. Can you post more fully what you're trying to do, perhaps the entire contents of the `OnClick` Sub?